# Delete data from Access on DGV

Tags: .net, database, vb.net, datagridview

I am using a DGV with data bound items from an access 2010.
However, I only know how to delete one. Like this :

```
Dim ID = Integer.Parse(dgvMarkers.SelectedRows(0).Cells("colID").Value.ToString())
Dim query = "DELETE FROM tblMarkers WHERE ID = " & ID
```

How can I delete multiple selected entries?
I tried this one, but it doesn't seem to catch all rows that I selected, still the last one I clicked and its the only one deleted.

```
Dim ID = Integer.Parse(dgvFarrowing.SelectedRows(0).Cells("ID").Value.ToString())
    Dim query As String = "DELETE FROM tblPiglets WHERE ID = " & ID
    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(query, con)
        For Each r In dgvFarrowing.SelectedRows
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
    MessageBox.Show("Deleted", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to build comma separated values to be used in SQL `IN()` statement is using `String.Join` function :

```
If dgvMarkers.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
    Dim ids As New List(Of String)
    For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgvMarkers.SelectedRows
        ids.Add(r.Cells("ID").Value.ToString)
    Next
    'can use ids directly instead of ids.ToArray() in .NET 4 or above
    Dim query = "DELETE FROM tblMarkers WHERE ID IN (" & String.Join(",", ids.ToArray()) & ")"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    'Try this.
    'Set first the dgvMarkers.SelectionMode to FullRowSelect

    If dgvMarkers.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim id As New System.Text.StringBuilder

        For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgvMarkers.SelectedRows
            id.Append(r.Cells("ID").Value.ToString)
            id.Append(",")
        Next

        id.Remove(id.Length - 1, 1) 'remove the last comma

        Dim query = "DELETE FROM tblMarkers WHERE ID IN (" & id.ToString & ")"
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
  If dgvMarkers.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim id as String

        For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgvMarkers.SelectedRows
           id=r.Cells("ID").Value.ToString & ","
           dgvMarkers.Rows.Remove(r)
        Next

        id=id.Trim(",") 'remove the last comma

        Dim query = "DELETE FROM tblMarkers WHERE ID IN (" & id & ")"
    End If
```